# What command(s) control the behavior of /etc/rc*.d on Redhat/CentOS?

Tags: linux, system, centos, redhat, init

```
/etc/init.d/*


/etc/rc{1-5}.d/*
```

Comment: Do you mean what configures them, or what runs appropriate entries at startup/shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in one word: `init`.

This process always has pid of 1 and controls (spawns) all other processes in your unix according to the rules in `/etc/init.d`.

init is usually called with a number as an argument, e.g. `init 3` This will make it run the contents of the `rc3.d` folder.

For more information: [Wikipedia article for init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).

Edit: Forgot to mention, what actually controls what rc level you start off in is your bootloader.

Answer (score 2):

`/sbin/chkconfig` — The `/sbin/chkconfig` utility is a simple command line tool for maintaining the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/` directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by px, the proper way to manage the links to scripts from /etc/init.d to /etc/rc?.d is the /sbin/chkconfig command.

Scripts should have comments near the top that specify how chkconfig is to handle them. For example, /etc/init.d/httpd:

```
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: Apache is a World Wide Web server.  It is used to serve \
#          HTML files and CGI.
# processname: httpd
# config: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
# config: /etc/sysconfig/httpd
# pidfile: /var/run/httpd.pid
```

Also, use the /sbin/service command to start and stop services when run from the shell.